# How to fill multiple gridview in single database call using jquery ajax in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I know how to fill multiple gridview in single database call. I do following
in Sql server

```
select * from Table1
select * from Table2
select * from Table3
```

and in c#

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
Gridview1.DataBind;
GridView2.DataSource = ds.tables[1];
Gridview2.DataBind;
GridView3.DataSource = ds.tables[2];
Gridview3.DataBind;
```

But in AjaxCall c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRecords()
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = Cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Mysp_pro";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("option", "ShowRecords".Trim());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds);           
        return ds.GetXml();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Dispose();
        Cn.Close();
}
```

Jquery

```
success: function (response){
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var browsedata = xml.find("Table");
            var row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            $("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
            $.each(browsedata, function () {
                var detail = $(this);
                $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("Sr").text());
                $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("Department").text());
                $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("Provider").text());
              });
}
```

I don't know how can I break DataSet into different DataTables returned by Database in jquery.
Please suggest me.

Comment: Show us your xml returned by ajax method

Comment: I edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Show us your xml and we can see which selector to use

Comment: I didn't understand. How can I show you the xml ?

Comment: Just copy data from http response. xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d) - What is in response.d?